# I want to give a timer to the session and end it

Tags: php

```
<?php

function saveUsers($onlineusers_file){
    $file_save=fopen("onlineusers.txt","w+");
    flock($file_save,LOCK_EX);
    for($line=0;$line<count($onlineusers_file);$line++){
        fputs($file_save,$onlineusers_file[$line]."\n");
    };
    flock($file_save,LOCK_UN);
    fclose($file_save);
}

$onlineusers_file=file("onlineusers.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
if (isset($_POST['user'],$_POST['oper'])){
    $user=$_POST['user'];
    $oper=$_POST['oper'];
    $userexist=in_array($user,$onlineusers_file);
    if ($userexist)$userindex=array_search($user,$onlineusers_file);

    if($oper=="signin" && $userexist==false){
        $onlineusers_file[]=$user;
        saveUsers($onlineusers_file);

        echo "signin";
        exit();
    }

    if($oper=="signin" && $userexist==true){
        echo "userexist please enter other name";
        exit();
    }

    if($oper=="signout" && $userexist==true){
        array_splice($onlineusers_file,$userindex,1);
        saveUsers($onlineusers_file);
        echo "signout";
        exit();
    }

    if($oper=="signout" && $userexist==false){
        echo "usernotfound";
        exit();
    }
}
$olu=join("<br>",$onlineusers_file);
echo $olu;


?>
```

I have taken this script from online and I wanted to start and end session timeout here.

Comment: sorry i have to write "z" this cause it was not submitting

Comment: So, what have you tried yourself, so far?

Comment: i have tried to start and end session with if loop but it don't work properly

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you want to store the time when the sessions started

```
<?php
  $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
?
```

Then on another request check their session time (below example is based on 10 minutes) so if their initial session was requested more then 10 minutes the session is invalidated. Otherwise its still valid

```
<?php
  if ($_SESSION['timeout'] + 10 * 60 < time()) {
     // session timed out
  } else {
     // session ok
  }
?>
```

Also point to note: The session timeout is also dependant on your php.ini. If the value in ini file is i.e 5 minutes then the session will be invalidated after 5 minutes - regardless of what you specify in your code.